# Плагин для обрезки изображения

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть ли простой, как трактор, плагин для кропа картинок? Просто задается размер квадрата (именно квадрата) для вырезки и все

т.е. сам плагин априори не должен поддерживать возможность вытянуть одну сторону больше другой, всякие анимации и прочий бред, решение взять какой-нибудь jcrop и подогнать настройки под задачу совсем не устраивает, мне не нужен универсальный плагин

Comment: В канвасе напиши, максимум строк 40 будет